# Google Drive deleted collaborators files - attempting recovery

Tags: google-drive

A few hours ago, the google drive on my computer started to display sync errors. At some point between then and now, most of the files in a particular sub-folder (shared with collaborators) were deleted - I have no idea why or how that happened, but it was not intentional and I took no actions even close to doing that.

I found the files in my recycle bin and restored them. However, whilst many of the files now uploaded correctly, a number of the files did not sync properly - these seem to be almost all not actual files, but links to online files (i.e. a document has .gdoc at the end of it). These files are now missing from the online drive which my collaborators use (a fairly big problem!).

They are all presenting one of the following sync errors:

- Download Error: You only have permission to view this file, so your changes cannot be synced.
- Upload Error: This file points to an invalid online Google Doc.
- Download Error: Cannot remove because conflicting changes are still pending.

The fixes for these errors seem to involve deleting the files, which I definetely don't want to do, as that loses us our last connection to the files. The first error is particularly weird! It implies that I don't have permission to restore a file, just delete it. The second error worries me the most.

Note, if I click on the files (which are links) then I get told I need permission to open the file, yet I did have permission. The learn more button suggests that the owner has deleted the file - yet as I said, that didn't happen (I don't actually own any of the files)

I'm using Firefox to browse, and my Google Drive is version 1.5, running on Windows XP.

Can anyone help?! Happy to provide more info.

Comment: You will have to get the original owner of the files to upload them again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today.
Google in its help docs suggests contacting them and I can confirm they did the job - fairly quickly too, it took a couple hours of e-mailing. It seems only their technicians can recover the files for you.